# weird issue with python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

the following super simple unit test runs fine under python2.7, but gave the following error
"no method runTest()" in 2.6, why is that?

thanks!
yang

```
myuser@myhost /tmp $ python26 -m unittest a.AA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/unittest.py", line 874, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/unittest.py", line 815, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/unittest.py", line 842, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/unittest.py", line 848, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/unittest.py", line 612, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/unittest.py", line 597, in loadTestsFromName
    test = obj()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/unittest.py", line 215, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName)
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'a.AA'>: runTest
myuser@myhost /tmp $ vi a.py
myuser@myhost /tmp $ cat a.py
import unittest

class AA(unittest.TestCase):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite [runTest](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) function in your class.

Or functions named test_something, wich unittest understands as test functions. This is helpful when you want to execute a conscequent number of tests, because you can provide setUp and tearDown, which are functions that are called before each test, to create classes or stuff that you need in your test.

Comment: thanks, but how come the first simple example in docs http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/unittest.html#basic-example     do not have the runTest() override?

Comment: Because it implements functions named test_something, wich unittest understands as test functions.

Comment: I added a test_blah() test, still the same

import unittest

class AA(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_blah(self):
        assertEquals(1,1,'simpl')

Comment: no, still the same error; I even added a suite() method, same error

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works in 2.7 and not in 2.6 is found right [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface).

It says

> Changed in version 2.7: In earlier versions it was only possible to run individual test methods and not modules or classes.

You are trying to run all the tests in your entire class `AA`.  You cannot do that in 2.6.  You can put a call to `unittest.main()` at the bottom of your code and run the script from the command line via `python a.py`.

```
$ cat a.py
import unittest

class AA(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

unittest.main()

$ python -V
Python 2.6.1
$ python a.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

You might also want to guard the call to `unittest.main()` to make sure it is only called if you run this file from the command line.